# What's the meaning of extra variables present in constraints, but not in the objective?

Tags: optimization

What's the meaning of extra variables present in constraints, but not in the objective?

E.g.

$$\min (x_1,x_2)$$
$$s.t. x_1+x_2-x_3 \geq 1$$

Does this mean that $x_3$ is redundant, since it's not present in the objective?

Comment: Yea, it is redundant, assuming that all the variables must be non-negative.

Comment: Often extra variables are added as "slack variables" to convert inequalities into equalities.  For example, minimizing $f(x,y)$ subject to $x+y \leq 3$ is the same as minimizing $f(x,y)$ subject to $x+y+z = 3$ with $z \geq 0$.

Comment: @JairTaylor True, but in this case, it is both an inequality and has a so-called slack variable.

Comment: @DonThousand Sure, I wasn't referring to this particular example. Here $x_3$ is in fact redundant in the sense that $\min(x_1,x_2)$ subject to $x_1 + x_2 -x_3 \geq 1$ is the same as $\min(x_1,x_2)$ subject to $x_1 + x_2 \geq 1$. (both are $-\infty$)

Answer (score 1):

They impose constraints, they can  influence the values of the other variables that are present in the objective function.

For example $$\max x_1$$

subject to $$x_1+x_2 =1 .$$
$$x_2\ge 0.5$$

Hence even though $x_2$ doesn't appear in the objective function, they impose the constraint that $x_1 \le \frac12$.

Comment: Yes, but not in this case. (Again, assuming that as in most linear programming problems, variables must be non-negative)